# how to define shell command output as globally accessible from other stages Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, cicd

How to access shell command output value into the if-condition , if 'retval' value is 'False' I want to stop executing other stages

**error**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $env for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

code:

```
stage('GitHub API Commit Statuses'){
        container('terra'){
          ansiColor('xterm'){
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'launchpad-pat', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PAT')]){
              try{
                env.retval = ''
                sh '''
                  env.retval=$(bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/pr_file_changes.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $pr_number $working_dir)
                  if [ "$env.retval" = "True" ]
                  then
                     echo "success"
                     echo "retval: $retval"
                     bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/create-commit-status.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $branch_name pending $BUILD_URL "The Jenkins pipeline is running" $working_dir
                 
                  else
                    echo "retval: $env.retval"
                  fi 
                '''    
              }
              catch (exc){
                echo exc.toString()
                
                echo "GitHub API commit statuses creation has been failed for the git repo:${repo_name} and it continues to execute next stages"
              }
              if ( $env.retval == 'False' ){
                  error('stop')
              }
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a good write up in this [Jenkins Pipeline Environment Variables - The Definitive Guide](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/) blog. See the "Overriding environment variables" section specifically.

Please excuse me if I misunderstand but I don't think you need this env var. Rearrange it so that before the try block you do `sh "bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/pr_file_changes.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $pr_number $working_dir"` . Inside the try block run `sh "bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/create-commit-status.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $branch_name pending $BUILD_URL "The Jenkins pipeline is running" $working_dir"`.

If `pr_file_changes.sh` fails with non 0 exit code then your pipeline will stop, and just like your current logic the `create-commit-status.sh` script won't run.

Here is a small **working** example of what I mean

```bash
node {
    stage('example'){
        sh "echo 'Call pr_file_changes.sh' "
        try {
            sh "echo 'Call create-commit-status.sh' "
        } catch (exc) {
            echo 'GitHub API commit statuses creation has been failed for the git .....'
        }
    }
    
    stage('Next'){
        echo "This was next"
    }
}
```

Here is your code block rearranged but untested

```bash
stage('GitHub API Commit Statuses'){
        container('terra'){
          ansiColor('xterm'){
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'launchpad-pat', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PAT')]){
              // Run pr_file_changes.sh and stop everything if it fails
              sh "bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/pr_file_changes.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $pr_number $working_dir"
              try{
                // Run create-commit-status.sh if pr_file_changes.sh was successful
                // but I want to carry on if this fails so I put it
                // in a try/catch block
                sh "bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/create-commit-status.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $branch_name pending $BUILD_URL "The Jenkins pipeline is running" $working_dir "
              }
              catch (exc){
                echo exc.toString()
                echo "GitHub API commit statuses creation has been failed for the git repo:${repo_name} and it continues to execute next stages"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code I got my expected out put.

```
stage('GitHub API Commit Statuses'){
        container('terra'){
          ansiColor('xterm'){
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '****', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PAT')]){
              def retval = ''
              try{
                 retval = sh(script: '''
                  a=$(bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/pr_file_changes.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $pr_number $working_dir )
                  echo "\$a"
                ''', returnStdout: true)
                
                echo "ret:$retval"
                sh """
                  
                  if [ "$retval" = "True" ]
                    then
                      echo "success"
                      echo "retval: $retval"
                      bash terraform-azure-pipelines/scripts/create-commit-status.sh $USERNAME $PAT $repo_name $branch_name pending $BUILD_URL "The Jenkins pipeline is running" $working_dir
                 
                  else
                    echo "retval: $retval"
                  fi 
                """    
              }
              catch (exc){
                echo exc.toString()
                
                echo "GitHub API commit statuses creation has been failed for the git repo:${repo_name} and it continues to execute next stages"
              }
              if ( retval.contains('False') ){
                  error('stop')
              }
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).